# Rails, how to query database for associated entries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a query interface for a small archive and need to understand how I can query the database for associated entries such as keywords, authors and so on.

I have a Resource model with a series of columns for each entry as well as a series of associations such as authors, keywords, etc.

```
class Resource < ApplicationRecord

# Associations
  belongs_to :bibliographic_level
  belongs_to :editor
  belongs_to :fund
  belongs_to :land
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Resource"
  belongs_to :resource_collocation
  belongs_to :resource_type
  has_many :resource_authors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :authors, through: :resource_authors
  has_many :items, class_name: "Resource", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :resource_keywords, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keywords, through: :resource_keywords
...
```

In my Controller I define an action for the database query

```
  def opac    
    @resources = Resource.page(params[:page]).order('id ASC').per_page(10).search(params)
  end
```

In my model I created different search enquiries based on the fact that the user chooses any, title, author or keyword as mask for his search.

```
  def self.restricted_search(params)
    if params[:searchAny].present?
      all.where(['title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', "%#{params[:searchAny]}%", "%#{params[:searchAny]}%"])
    elsif params[:searchTitle].present?
      where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:searchTitle]}%")
    ...
  end
```

How can I query the database and get all resources displayed where part of the author name contains "Mich" or which has a certain keyword "X" associated?

I suppose something such as this

```
    elsif params[:searchAuthor].present?
      joins(:resource_authors).where('resource_authors.authors_name = ?', "%#{params[:searchAuthor]}%")
    elsif params[:searchKeyword].present?
      joins(:resource_keywords).where('resource_keywords.keyword_word = ?', "%#{params[:searchKeyword]}%")
  end
```

The syntax is not clear to me, since in both cases a resource can have multiple authors and I would have to ask for all resources where one author contains a certain string.

How can i get this working?

Thank you in advance.

### **Addition**

When querying for author I get the following output in my log:

```
  Resource Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `resources`.* FROM `resources` INNER JOIN `resource_authors` ON `resource_authors`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id` INNER JOIN `authors` ON `authors`.`id` = `resource_authors`.`author_id` INNER JOIN `resource_authors` `resource_authors_authors_join` ON `resource_authors_authors_join`.`author_id` = `authors`.`id` INNER JOIN `resources` `resources_authors` ON `resources_authors`.`id` = `resource_authors_authors_join`.`resource_id` WHERE (resource_type_id != '7') AND (resource_authors_resources_join.author_name = '%test%') ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

and this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Column 'resource_type_id' in where clause is ambiguous):
     99:             <%= will_paginate @restricted_resources, previous_label: h("<"), next_label: h(">"), class: "pagination" %>
```

When querying for keywords I get:

```
  Resource Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `resources`.* FROM `resources` INNER JOIN `resource_keywords` ON `resource_keywords`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id` WHERE (resource_type_id != '7') AND (resource_keywords.keyword_word = '%test%') ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

and the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'resource_keywords.keyword_word' in 'where clause'):
     99:             <%= will_paginate @restricted_resources, previous_label: h("<"), next_label: h(">"), class: "pagination" %>
```

Comment: Code you've written suggest `resource_authors` has a string column named `authors_name` and `resource_keywords` has a string column `keyword_word`. Can you confirm? Can you add error you got with current queries you're making? Do you want to search on both in the same time `searchAuthor` **and** `searchKeyword` or separately like you're doing currently?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a `resource` model and `author` and `keywords` are different models and tables connected each time through a join table `resource_authors` and `resource_keywords`. I want to add logic where you search either in the title, the author, keywords or in everything at the same time. For now everything means title and description ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're need to target the correct table and use `LIKE` instead of `=`.

```
elsif params[:searchAuthor].present?
  joins(:authors)
     .where('authors.authors_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:searchAuthor]}%")
elsif params[:searchKeyword].present?
  joins(:keywords)
     .where('keywords.keyword_word LIKE ?', "%#{params[:searchKeyword]}%")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. With your corrections I get the following messages: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'authors.authors_name' in 'where clause'` for the author query and `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'keywords.keyword_word' in 'where clause'` for the keyword query.

Comment: You haven't actually added your schema to the question so you'll have to put on your thinking cap and actually try to understand the code instead of just copy-pasting.

Comment: SQL strings in join and especially nested join queries are what I do not understand in this scenario. I rewrote your line into `joins(:authors).where(authors: {name: "%#{params[:searchAuthor]}%"})` and it loads, but does not get an entry.

Comment: That won't work since it generates `WHERE authors.name  = ?` and not `WHERE authors.name LIKE ?` If the column is named `name` then just change the query slightly. Its SQL - not rocket science.

Comment: `=` would only match rows where the name column actually contains `%foo%` - it's the exact same problem as your original code.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. To me joint queries are rocket science ;0) I have queries such as this: `@keywords = Keyword.joins(magazines: :keywords).where('keywords_magazines_magazines_join.keyword_id = ?', @keyword.id)` and I really need to learn how to write the sql string part. That is something I really would like to learn. I suspect that it is difficult for me, because active records, sql and joins collide. Thanks again!!!! In case you had any resource where I could do my research, that would be great.